# Start date and finish date validation - Entity Hibernate java

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, entity

I have entity with code like this:

```
@URL
private String organizerLink;
private LocalDate startDate;
private LocalDate finishDate;
```

I want to be sure that user first set 'startDate' before (or the same day) 'finishDate'.

BTW:

Is there option to add if statement here?

For example:

```
`if (startDate > finishDate) {
return false;
} else {
return true;
}`
```

Comment: You could implement a constraint validator https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-method-constraints

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the Date API? You can view the API Here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Because your start and end date can be on the same day, I suggest that you also include a time function, so when you compare the dates (if same day) the end date time will always be greater than the start date time. As to verify if the user has entered a start date, use: 
`if(startDate.toString().equals("")){// show error msg}` (empty string) method within the if statement.